# How to customize the Bootstrap carousel to have some text static and some chang with each background picture

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm still new to Bootstrap and would like some examples on how to achieve the following design idea.

We would like to have a carousel on our home page where the company name (left aligned) remains visible the whole time. The carousel will have about 5 background images and with each image (full width and darker overlay) a specific bold white text to describe one of the company services.

How can this be achieved easilly with Bootstrap?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve it you can do the following :

- Position your company name element inside the carousel-inner div but not into a .carousel-item div. It will prevent to slide like the carousel-item divs
- Into every slide, insert an element for the service company, and an image for the background.

So the code could be :

```
<div id="carousel-ID" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <h2>Company name</h2>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <h3>Company service 1</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <h3>Company service 2</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <h3>Company service 3</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <h3>Company service 4</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <h3>Company service 5</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, use CSS to adjust the positioning of the `<h2>`, each `<h3>`, and the background image, like so :

```
 .carousel h2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3; // To appear above the slides
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
  }
  .carousel-item {
    // position: relative; // Just for info, already set in Bootstrap.
  }
  .carousel-item h3 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10rem; // Adjust here the space from top
    margin-left: 3rem;  // Adjust here the space from left
    z-index: 2; // To appear above the image
  }
  .carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; // To appear below the h3
  }
```

The code may be adjusted to match Bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using any data from bootstrap documentation in this link : [bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

1- using Nabar : link-> [bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/)
2- slider images : link -> [slider](http://%20https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/)
3- using bootstrap layout grid to divide  your page with responsive design : link -> [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Good Luck!